# SQLite- heading above ListView (source same as ListView source)

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite

Im busy with a Bible app, I use an SQLite db from my assets folder to retrieve the data, I use 3 listviews, each in its own activity, it goes like this:

**DB column names:** Book name, book id, chapter number, chapter id, verse text, verse id

**1st activity**, user selects a book, Genesis, Exodus, Leviticus, etc... and 2nd activity starts

**2nd activity**, db gets filtered so user can select chapters under that book...and 3rd activity starts

**3rd activity**, db gets filtered and shows all the verses under that chapter...

What I want is to put a text view at the top of the 2nd list view and then after the user selected from the 1st listview and the 2nd activity starts to show all chapters, it should show the book name that was selected from the 1st activity. And in the 3rd list view it should show the book name and chapter number that was selected from the previous two activities, I've tried using the intend, but I get errors.

**Adapter:**

```
    public class customAdapterHoofstuk extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext;
        private List<defineBybeldbAlles> defineBybeldbAlles;

        public customAdapterHoofstuk(Context mContext, List<defineBybeldbAlles> defineBybelDBList) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.defineBybeldbAlles = defineBybelDBList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return defineBybeldbAlles.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return defineBybeldbAlles.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return (defineBybeldbAlles.get(position).getHoofstuk_id());
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.custom_row_hoofstuk, null);

//this works->
            TextView hoofstuknommer = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.custom_row_hoofstuktext);
            hoofstuknommer.setText (defineBybeldbAlles.get(position).getHoofstuk_nommer());

//this works-->
            TextView hoofstukid = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.hoofstuk_id);
            hoofstukid.setText(String.valueOf(defineBybeldbAlles.get(position).getHoofstuk_id()));

//this doesnt work->
            TextView boeknaambyhoofstuk = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.boeknaambyhoofstuklys);
            boeknaambyhoofstuk.setText(defineBybeldbAlles.get(position).get_hebreeus());

            return v;
        }
        }
```

**Activity where it should be shown:**

```
public class BybelActivityHoofstuk extends Activity {
    private ListView listviewHoofstuk;
    private customAdapterHoofstuk adapter_customAdapterHoofstuk;
    private List<defineBybeldbAlles> defineBybeldbAllesList;
    private DBHandlerHoofstuk DBHandlerHoofstuk;


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> HoofstukList;

    //Boek id
    String boek_id_na_hoofstuk;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bybel_hoofstuk);
        listviewHoofstuk = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.BybelHoofstukListView);
        DBHandlerHoofstuk = new DBHandlerHoofstuk(this);

        //Check exists database
        File Database = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DBHandlerHoofstuk.DBNAME);
        if(false == Database.exists()){
            DBHandlerHoofstuk.getReadableDatabase();}

            //Get boek id
            Intent boekIntent = getIntent();
            boek_id_na_hoofstuk = boekIntent.getStringExtra("boek_id");

            //hashmap for listview
            HoofstukList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            //Get bybel list in db when db exists
            defineBybeldbAllesList = DBHandlerHoofstuk.getListHoofstuk(boek_id_na_hoofstuk);

            //Init adapter
            adapter_customAdapterHoofstuk = new customAdapterHoofstuk(this,defineBybeldbAllesList);

            //Set adapter for listview
            listviewHoofstuk.setAdapter(adapter_customAdapterHoofstuk);

            //Listview item click listener
            //BybelActivityVers will be launched by passing hoofstuk_id
            listviewHoofstuk.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3){

                    //on selecting a hoofstk
                    //BybelActivityVers will be launched to show verse inside
                    Intent hoofstukIntent = new Intent(BybelActivityHoofstuk.this,BybelActivityVers.class);

                    //send hoofstuk_id to VersActivity to get verse under that book
                    String hoofstuk_id_na_vers = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.hoofstuk_id)).getText().toString();
                    hoofstukIntent.putExtra("hoofstuk_id", hoofstuk_id_na_vers);
                    startActivity(hoofstukIntent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**DBHandler:**

```
public class DBHandlerHoofstuk extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DBNAME = "pwl14082016-5.db";
    public static final String DBLOCATION = "location goes here";

    private Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    public static final String COLUMN_BOEK_ID = "boek_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_HEBREEUS = "_hebreeus";
    public static final String COLUMN_AFRIKAANS = "_afrikaans";
    public static final String COLUMN_HOOFSTUK_ID = "hoofstuk_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_HOOFSTUK_NOMMER = "hoofstuk_nommer";
    public static final String COLUMN_VERS_ID = "vers_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_VERS_NOMMER = "vers_nommer";
    public static final String COLUMN_VERS_TEXT = "vers_text";

    public DBHandlerHoofstuk(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    //Blank want db bestaan klaar
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    //blank want db word ekstern geupgrade
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    //maak db oop
    public void opendatabase(){
        String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
        if (mDatabase !=null && mDatabase.isOpen()) {
            return;
        }

        //verander dalk na 'mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);' as OPEN_READONLY nie werk nie
        mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    //maak db toe
    public void closeDatabase(){
        if (mDatabase!=null) {
            mDatabase.close();
        }
    }

    public List<defineBybeldbAlles> getListHoofstuk(String boek_id_na_hoofstuk){
        defineBybeldbAlles defineBybeldbHoofstuk = null;
        List<defineBybeldbAlles> defineBybeldbAllesList = new ArrayList<>();
        opendatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PWLBybel WHERE " + COLUMN_BOEK_ID + " = '" + boek_id_na_hoofstuk + "'GROUP BY hoofstuk_id ORDER BY hoofstuk_id * 1 ASC", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            defineBybeldbHoofstuk = new defineBybeldbAlles(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getInt(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getInt(5),cursor.getString(6),cursor.getString(7));
            defineBybeldbAllesList.add(defineBybeldbHoofstuk);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        closeDatabase();
        return defineBybeldbAllesList;
}
}
```

**XML where it gets displayed:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".defineBybeldbAlles">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/BybelHoofstukListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#ff303030"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Boek naam:"
        android:id="@+id/boeknaambyhoofstuklys"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#000063"
        android:textSize="20dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: You don't need text inside the ListView. You just need to pass your string across the Intent and set a Textview that is above the ListView

Comment: @USKMobility I'll run the code tonight after work and get back to you

Comment: @cricket_007 I've got it like that yes... Textview above the listview. Could you please tell me, in the customadapter I use to inflate textviews for my 2nd activity, how would this code look like when retrieving the string from an intend passed from 1st activity? And in the 3rd activity, inflate 2 textviews from intends passed from the 1st and 2nd activities...?

Comment: The code should be the same for passing any data between activities using intents. Please edit your question with the errors you are seeing and the code you tried

Comment: Please see edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone might come across this, I wasn't able to pass the book and chapter name to the heading or bar, but I was able to figure out to set a title.

In your manifest under each activity, just put in `android:label="title here"`
to at least get a heading or title you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the string through intent using

```
String KEY  = "PUT_ANY_KEY_HERE";
String VALUE = "BOOK_NAME/CHAPTER_NAME";
Intent i = new Intent(FROM_CLASS.this, TO_CLASS.class);
i.putExtra(KEY,VALUE);
startActivity(i);
```

and get the string in the 2nd activity using

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent!=null)
    String VALUE = intent.getExtras().getString(KEY);
```

now set the VALUE string in your textview. Also you need to put the chapterName textview above your listview or add the VALUE string as your 1st entry in the arraylist that you might be using to populate listview in 2nd and 3rd activity.

Comment: I'm already using this method to open my activities, so my id's gets passed to next activities to filter db. How could I pass the book name or chapter number that was clicked to my adapter, so that it inflates that value that was passed?

Comment: You can directly pass name of the book and chapter as a string also Post your logs to check what exactly the error is